# Using Bonjour without installing framework on Win7

Tags: .net, windows, bonjour

I downloaded Bonjour SDK for windows, and learned from the Chat example how you add bonjour service to your program. This worked fine. But on a fresh installed Win 7 machine I only get error messages.

Do I always have to install Bonjour framework before any program can run Bonjour or did I simply ship the wron dlls?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have to distribute the framework.

After you install the SDK on the development machine, in the C:\Program Files\Bonjour\Installer (or the custom path where you installed it), there are two installers (32 and 64 bit). You should distribute those and install them prior to running your program.

You can read more here: https://developer.apple.com/softwarelicensing/agreements/bonjour.html#bonjourwin